# Using awk to read and create files in all subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting, subdirectory

I am trying to parse all files named "README" in all subdirectories (and sub-subdirectories) under my specified directory, and create a new file containing the parsed output in the same directory where each "README" file was found.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=$(find myDirectory -type f -name 'README')
for f in $FILES
do
   #this is fine
   echo "parsing $f"

   #this is not fine
   awk -F, 'BEGIN {print "header"};
   {print $2;}
   END {print "footer";}' $f > outputfile

done
```

The output file is only being created in my working directory. What I would like this to do is to perhaps redirect the output files into the subdirectories where their corresponding README's were found. Is there a better way than this?

If it helps, README format:

```
something,something2,something3
nothing1,nothing2,nothing3
```

Comment: In what way does "placing the `awk` command in the `for` loop" not work?  What does the echo give you?  What is the error message from `awk`?  The output file is going to be in the current directory each time, so you'll need to do some moving of the file after you've created it.  You won't be moving it over the README file until after you're confident that the script works correctly — unless you've a secret hate for your README files, in which case there are easier ways to mutilate them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There is no error. The outputfile is simply not created in the subdirectories. echo gives me "parsing subdirectoryName README" for each instance of README found. And yes the output file is only created in my current directory. The README's in each subdirectory are intended to be different, so i don't think moving them about would be the right way to go.

Comment: Well, that's where you told the script to create it, so it did as you commanded.  If you want to do it differently, that's OK too; decide what you want and do it.  You need to rework your question to explain what you think is going wrong, and exactly what you want to achieve.  It's straight-forward to create the output file in the directory where the README came from — you can either use the `dirname` command or investigate shell parameter expansion methods to manage the problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, ok then. Not too sure about how to go about doing that either. Perhaps my question should have been about how to redirect files into subdirectories where certain files are found.

Comment: Yes, that is probably the question you need to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you want the output file created in the directory where the README was found, the simplest way is to use the POSIX standard [`dirname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html)
command:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=$(find myDirectory -type f -name 'README')
for f in $FILES
do
    outputfile="$(dirname "$f")/outputfile"
    echo "parsing $f into $outputfile"

    awk -F, 'BEGIN {print "header"}
             {print $2}
             END {print "footer"}' "$f" > "$outputfile"

done
```

This code is not safe if there are spaces or newlines in the directories, but assuming you stick with the portable file name character set (letters, digits, dot, dash and underscore), there'll be no major problems.  (It wasn't safe before I made any changes; it still isn't safe.  It isn't safe because you used `FILES=$(find …)` and while you do that, it is pretty much guaranteed to remain unsafe for names with blanks, tabs, newlines in them.  There are ways to fix that, but they involve more major surgery.)

If you want, you can study the Bash [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) mechanisms to see how to do it without using `dirname`.

Comment: Thank you. And thanks for the tip. I'll look into it.